# automatic mean of multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with multiple variables. I am trying to group these variables according to the end of the name of variable and calculate the mean of each group. Here is an example of my dataset:

```py
data = {'AST_0-01': [1, 2, 3], 
        'AST_0-02': [4, 5, 6],
        'AST_1-01': [7, 8, 9],
        'AST_1-02': [1, 2, 3],
        'AST_2-01': [4, 5, 6],
        'AST_2-02': [7, 8, 9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I am trying to do is to group the variables that ends with the same number, e.g.: `[AST_0-01, AST_1-01, AST_2-01]`, `[AST_0-02, AST_1-02, AST_2-02]`, and then get the means.

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please mark it as accepted so that your question can be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "transpose" your dataframe so that you can group by the string names

```py
In [3]: df = df.T.reset_index()

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
      index  0  1  2
0  AST_0-01  1  2  3
1  AST_0-02  4  5  6
2  AST_1-01  7  8  9
3  AST_1-02  1  2  3
4  AST_2-01  4  5  6
5  AST_2-02  7  8  9

In [5]: df.groupby(df["index"].str[-2:]).mean()
Out[5]:
         0    1    2
index
01     4.0  5.0  6.0
02     4.0  5.0  6.0
```

This mean is broken out into the three separate rows in the original dataframe, but if you want the "total" mean, then

```py
In [6]: df.groupby(df["index"].str[-2:]).mean().sum(axis=1)
Out[6]:
index
01    15.0
02    15.0
dtype: float64
```